# Tooltip on datagrid column in gwt

Tags: gwt, datagrid

** Tooltip on datagrid Column just put this code in constructor  **

```
T = model class;  

dataGrid.addCellPreviewHandler(new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<T>() {

                @Override
                public void onCellPreview(final CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
                    if ("mouseover".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
                        String str = "";
                        Element cellElement = event.getNativeEvent()
                        .getEventTarget().cast();
                        int row = event.getIndex();
                        int col = event.getColumn();
                        T model = (T) dataGrid
                        .getVisibleItem(row);
                        str = "" + dataGrid.getColumn(col).getValue(model);
                        cellElement.setTitle(str);

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @vineet That's nice that you've found a way to set a tooltip on a column. But it would be much more helpful and easier to find by other users if you follow an instruction on [answering your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Adam I place answer not any question to help other. :)

Comment: @VineetChaudhary I think you want this to be a wiki page, you should make one, it's a good solution.